# Allowing ics to open in phonegap app for iOS

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, cordova, icalendar

So I've used this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496629/create-ics-file-on-the-fly-using-javascript-or-jquery) slightly augmented to work on iOS to create an ics file on the fly.

```
msgData1 = $('.start-time').text();
msgData2 = $('.end-time').text();
msgData3 = $('.Location').text();

var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::me@gmail.com\nDTSTART:" + msgData1 +"\nDTEND:" + msgData2 +"\nLOCATION:" + msgData3 + "\nSUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";

$('.test').click(function(){
    var icslink = "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG);
    $(this).attr("href", icslink);
});
```

It works when I view my app straight from safari, however when I view it through phonegap it doesn't work at all. Nothing happens.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I guess that's because phonegap doesn't know how to handle `data:text/calendar`, just like my Firefox 26

Answer (score 0):

The calendar plugins here worked perfectly!

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins