# Handle .ICS files in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, icalendar

we've got an app that includes a few links to external .ICS (calendar appointments). In safari it's handled fine however in Phonegap they're not. We've tried opening them in the InAppBrowser and we just get a loading error.

Ideally, we need people to be able to click these external .ICS files and have them handled in a normal way (iphones open iCal, android opens calendar and adds the event, etc).

Any suggestions? We can't get links to open in Safari while having the InAppBrowser installed so we can even seem to push users out to safari.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166561/allowing-ics-to-open-in-phonegap-app-for-ios

Comment: Have you tried using calendar plugin? https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a plugin for that. Check out [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-calendar).

Answer (score 0):

We've managed to solve this by pushing the links to the calendar files out to safari - it seems to get picked up before it even opens safari and pops up with the nice 'add to calendar' dialog while still in our app. Perfect :)

Comment: How do you push the links to Safari?  InAppBrowser?  That's what I'm trying to do, but it's not working.  What settings are you using?