# .ics file handling on iOS with Ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic application and I have an .ics file URL returned from server, for example:

> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DeMarko/6142417/raw/1cd301a5917141524b712f92c2e955e86a1add19/sample.ics

How can I import it to calendar on iOS 9.3.2 ?
I tried to open it on Safari in order for safari to import to calendar, but it not works, it just prompt a dialog to subscribe to the ICS's event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610581/handle-ics-files-in-phonegap), Safari should show a prompt with 'add to Calendar', I unfortunately do not know enough about ICS's to see whether the problem may be with the file. Otherwise you can also check this [excellent Cordova plugin by Eddy Verbruggen](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that PhoneGap Calendar plugin did the job.