# iCal file download sends error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, safari, aem

I was able to put together this script that generates ics calendar files on the click of a button, but it will not work in IE or Safari.  Has anyone been able to get these ics file downloads to work in IE?  The browser doesn't recognize the file.

Every question I've seen online about this has very incomplete answers about "adding a header", whatever that means, so at the very least I figured I'd put out a complete html/js version that works in Chrome/Firefox w/ complete Date objects, iso8601 conversion, etc.  This is within a JSP file.

```
 <span class="start-date">01/13/2017</span>
 <span class="end-date">01/15/2017</span>
 <span class="start-time">1 PM</span>
 <span class="end-time">3 PM</span>
 <span class="event-title">NYC</span>
 <span class="event-location">NYC</span>

 <button class="createICS"> Add to Calendar </button>



<script>
var currentDateTime = iso8601Format(new Date().toISOString());
var startDateTime = iso8601Format(new Date($('.start-date').text() + " " + $('.start-time').text()).toISOString());
var endDateTime = iso8601Format(new Date($('.end-date').text() + " " + $('.end-time').text()).toISOString());
var eventLocation = $('.event-location').text();
var eventTitle = $('.event-title').text();
var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
"VERSION:2.0\n" +
"PRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\n" +
"BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
"DTSTAMP:" + currentDateTime + "\n" +
"DTSTART:" + startDateTime + "\n" +
"DTEND:" + endDateTime + "\n" +
"LOCATION:" + eventLocation + "\n" +
"SUMMARY:" + eventTitle + "\n" +
"END:VEVENT\n" +
"END:VCALENDAR";
console.log(icsMSG);

$('.createICS').click(function(){
    window.open("data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + encodeURIComponent(icsMSG));
});

function iso8601Format(dateTime) { // Converts date and time to the format we need: yyyyMMddThhmmssZ
    var dT = dateTime.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{3})Z$/,'$1$2$3T$4$5$6Z');
    return dT;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, you are trying to generated iCal with a Javascript function. This is ok for modern and more sophisticated browsers like Chrome and Firefox but it won't work for IE.

IE does not recognise an iCal file as it's not one of the [known MIME types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx) it can detect using the content format.

For IE to work with iCal file you will need to add the following response headers which can only be done from a server side:

```
content-type: text/calendar
content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.ics
```

Although this is IE specific it will work with Safari also as it pretty much works on same principles.

**JSP and Javascript**

Since you have mentioned JSP, even if you write Javascript code in a JSP, it won't be executed on server side, it's still executed on client side. JSP just renders the Javascript code.

**AEM Solution**

Your can probably change your logic in Java code and render the iCal file from your JSP if it is correctly hooked into the response stream. Alternatively, you can write a servlet to return this iCal file. This is because you need to add response headers and have full control of the response body (iCal content) in order to render the response properly and this can only be done from server side (at least to fix IE and Safari issues).

**More Information**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938890/javascript-generated-ics-file-opens-in-chrome-and-firefox-but-not-in-ie) SO question for related details.

Comment: what would that look like in a servlet returning the iCal file?  I haven't seen these response headers before, not sure how to use them.  I can find mozilla documentation on them but its not super helpful in implementing in java/jsp