# How to save a .ics file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

My javascript has constructed the contents of an ics (Apple Calendar app) file.

The user should be able to download this file, via a button and maybe a save dialog. I can't use a URI, because the file is too big so I get an error 414. I'd like the downloaded file to automatically have a .ics extension if possible. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `<a download=contact.ics href=/blah.ics>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496629/create-ics-file-on-the-fly-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)