# Create javascript ICS to add to calendar on ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, icalendar

I am trying to get this code from this question [create .ics file on the fly using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496629/create-ics-file-on-the-fly-using-javascript-or-jquery)  to work with no luck on an iphone and have it add to the calendar.

I have fields with the start and end times like so

```
<div class="start-time">9:30am</div>
<div class="end-time">10:30am</div>
<div class="Location">California</div>
<p><a href="#" class="test">Add to Calendar</a></p>
```

And my javascript/jQuery is like so

```
msgData1 = $('.start-time').text();
    msgData2 = $('.end-time').text();
    msgData3 = $('.Location').text();

    var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::me@gmail.com\nDTSTART:" + msgData1 +"\nDTEND:" + msgData2 +"\nLOCATION:" + msgData3 + "\nSUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";

    $('.test').click(function(){
        window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
    });
```

I have also created a fiddle but when testing on an iPhone it opens a new window and says it is trying to add a calendar event but when I click ok it says not valid.

https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/ce5xz6y9/10/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)
Thanks!

Comment: What sort of results are you getting when you test with non-mobile browser? What do you get on iPhone?

Comment: When it opens the new tab is says "This website is trying to show you a calendar invite. Do you want to allow this?" then when you say allow it says "Safari cant download this file".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wmznc6vq/20/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.test').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // Format: https://docs.fileformat.com/email/ics/
    var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\r\n";
    icsMSG += "PRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\r\n";
    icsMSG += "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
    icsMSG += "UID:me@google.com\r\n"
    icsMSG += "DTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\r\n";
    icsMSG += "ATTENDEE;CN=My Self;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\r\n";
    icsMSG += "ORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::me@gmail.com\r\n";
    icsMSG += "DTSTART:" + $('.start-time').text() + "\r\n";
    icsMSG += "DTEND:" + $('.end-time').text() + "\r\n";
    icsMSG += "LOCATION:" + $('.Location').text() + "\r\n";
    icsMSG += "SUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\r\n";
    icsMSG += "END:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR";
    var title = "newEvent.ics";
    var uri = "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG);
    var link = $("<a>", {
      href: uri,
      download: title,
      target: "_BLANK"
    }).html("").appendTo("body");
    link.get(0).click();
    link.remove();
  });
});
```

This is based on the following: [How to rename downloaded files from window.open() in javascript?](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/941360)

Also checked formatting from here: https://docs.fileformat.com/email/ics/ which suggests CRLF (`\r\n`).

More about Download attribute: https://caniuse.com/?search=download

Comment: This is awesome and works great in Chrome but on an iPhone testing the fiddle it says safari cannot download this file.

Comment: @Aaron did you try using https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wmznc6vq/20/show to launch just the HTML portion. It is better for testing on mobile devices. iOS may also be protecting the client from downloading a file. If it is still an issue, I can look at it again, just did not have an iPhone to test with.